# Graphs arcs on AMPL C++ API

Tags: graphs, c++, ampl

I am trying to model a routing instance in AMPL C++ API. The AMPL Book presents a strategy for modeling routing instances via AMPL (Figures 6-2a and 6-2b, Page 95, [Chapter 6](https://ampl.com/wp-content/uploads/Chapter-6-Compound-Sets-and-Indexing-AMPL-Book.pdf)), as it is presented below:

```
set V; # nodes
set A within {V,V}; # arcs
param cost{A}; # costs
```

However, I am having a hard time to find resources showing of how to achieve this by means of the AMPL C++ API. Below follows a C++ code with the parts in which I am lost.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 

#include "ampl/ampl.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace ampl;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    try {
        /* INPUT */

        // Nodes ids
        size_t n = 10;

        char ** V = (char **) malloc(n * sizeof(char*));
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            // up to 10 characters of id
            V[i] = (char *) malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
            sprintf(V[i], "%d", i);
        }

        // Arcs
        vector<pair<int, int>> A = {make_pair(1, 0), make_pair(2, 5)};

        /* AMPL process */
        AMPL ampl;

        // Sets
        // Nodes
        ampl.eval("set V;");
        ampl.getSet("V").setValues(V, n);

        // Arcs
        ampl.eval("set A within {V,V};");
        ampl.getSet("A");
        // how to set A???

        // cost
        ampl.eval("param cost{A};");
        ampl.getParameter("cost");
        // how to set populate cost???

        // Closing
        ampl.close();

        // Cleaning
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
            free(V[i]);
        free(V);

        return 0;
    } catch (const std::exception &e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << "\n";
        return 1;
    }
}
```

For those who want to replicate the experiments locally, just follow the steps of this [repo](https://github.com/matheusdiogenesandrade/AMPL_cmake.git).

I took the time to read the API documentation, specifically wrt to the classes [`Set`](https://portal.ampl.com/docs/api/latest/cpp/classes/set.html#_CPPv4N4ampl3SetE) and [`Parameter`](https://portal.ampl.com/docs/api/latest/cpp/classes/parameter.html#_CPPv4N4ampl9ParameterE), but I still couldn't find a way of using the functions `setValues`. I would like to know if anyone ever passed by such a situation before.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the API examples there is one with nodes, links and costs (https://ampl.com/api/latest/cpp/examples.html#example-4-operate-with-multidimensional-data) that is very similar to what you are trying to do. The following snippet uses `AMPL::setData` like in the multidimensional data example to pass a DataFrame with the elements of set `A` and the values for the parameter `cost`:

```cpp
ampl::AMPL ampl;

std::vector<double> V = {0, 1, 2, 5};
ampl.eval("set V;");
ampl.getSet("V").setValues(V.data(), V.size());

std::vector<std::pair<double, double>> A = {std::make_pair(1, 0), std::make_pair(2, 5)};
ampl.eval("set A within {V,V};");
ampl.eval("param cost{A};");
ampl.getParameter("cost");

ampl::DataFrame df(2, ampl::StringArgs("i", "j", "cost"));
std::vector<double> v1;
std::vector<double> v2;
std::vector<double> cost;
for (auto p : A)
{
  v1.push_back(p.first);
  v2.push_back(p.second);
  cost.push_back(3.14);
}
df.setColumn("i", v1.data(), v1.size());
df.setColumn("j", v2.data(), v2.size());
df.setColumn("cost", cost.data(), cost.size());
ampl.setData(df, "A");

ampl.eval("display cost;");
ampl.close();
```

Comment: Thank you very much!